# Understanding crc32

Tags: go, crc32

I try to understand the computation of crc32. It's new to me, so the question is a basic one. With the following code I have two different ways of computing the CRC32 sum. They should (in theory) be the same, but they differ. What am I doing wrong?

The Go stdlib implementation (what a surprise) seems to be correct, but I can't find the error in my implementation.

https://play.golang.org/p/QJH2K3IQEj

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "hash/crc32"
)

func main() {
    message := []byte("hello")
    // Is this the correct polynomial table? This is the table from
    // http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/repository/revisions/1cb52da49230c64c3719b4ab944ba1cf5a9abb92/entry/gr-digital/lib/digital_crc32.cc
    tbl := [256]uint32{0x00000000, 0x04C11DB7, 0x09823B6E, 0x0D4326D9,
        0x130476DC, 0x17C56B6B, 0x1A864DB2, 0x1E475005,
        0x2608EDB8, 0x22C9F00F, 0x2F8AD6D6, 0x2B4BCB61,
        0x350C9B64, 0x31CD86D3, 0x3C8EA00A, 0x384FBDBD,
        0x4C11DB70, 0x48D0C6C7, 0x4593E01E, 0x4152FDA9,
        0x5F15ADAC, 0x5BD4B01B, 0x569796C2, 0x52568B75,
        0x6A1936C8, 0x6ED82B7F, 0x639B0DA6, 0x675A1011,
        0x791D4014, 0x7DDC5DA3, 0x709F7B7A, 0x745E66CD,
        0x9823B6E0, 0x9CE2AB57, 0x91A18D8E, 0x95609039,
        0x8B27C03C, 0x8FE6DD8B, 0x82A5FB52, 0x8664E6E5,
        0xBE2B5B58, 0xBAEA46EF, 0xB7A96036, 0xB3687D81,
        0xAD2F2D84, 0xA9EE3033, 0xA4AD16EA, 0xA06C0B5D,
        0xD4326D90, 0xD0F37027, 0xDDB056FE, 0xD9714B49,
        0xC7361B4C, 0xC3F706FB, 0xCEB42022, 0xCA753D95,
        0xF23A8028, 0xF6FB9D9F, 0xFBB8BB46, 0xFF79A6F1,
        0xE13EF6F4, 0xE5FFEB43, 0xE8BCCD9A, 0xEC7DD02D,
        0x34867077, 0x30476DC0, 0x3D044B19, 0x39C556AE,
        0x278206AB, 0x23431B1C, 0x2E003DC5, 0x2AC12072,
        0x128E9DCF, 0x164F8078, 0x1B0CA6A1, 0x1FCDBB16,
        0x018AEB13, 0x054BF6A4, 0x0808D07D, 0x0CC9CDCA,
        0x7897AB07, 0x7C56B6B0, 0x71159069, 0x75D48DDE,
        0x6B93DDDB, 0x6F52C06C, 0x6211E6B5, 0x66D0FB02,
        0x5E9F46BF, 0x5A5E5B08, 0x571D7DD1, 0x53DC6066,
        0x4D9B3063, 0x495A2DD4, 0x44190B0D, 0x40D816BA,
        0xACA5C697, 0xA864DB20, 0xA527FDF9, 0xA1E6E04E,
        0xBFA1B04B, 0xBB60ADFC, 0xB6238B25, 0xB2E29692,
        0x8AAD2B2F, 0x8E6C3698, 0x832F1041, 0x87EE0DF6,
        0x99A95DF3, 0x9D684044, 0x902B669D, 0x94EA7B2A,
        0xE0B41DE7, 0xE4750050, 0xE9362689, 0xEDF73B3E,
        0xF3B06B3B, 0xF771768C, 0xFA325055, 0xFEF34DE2,
        0xC6BCF05F, 0xC27DEDE8, 0xCF3ECB31, 0xCBFFD686,
        0xD5B88683, 0xD1799B34, 0xDC3ABDED, 0xD8FBA05A,
        0x690CE0EE, 0x6DCDFD59, 0x608EDB80, 0x644FC637,
        0x7A089632, 0x7EC98B85, 0x738AAD5C, 0x774BB0EB,
        0x4F040D56, 0x4BC510E1, 0x46863638, 0x42472B8F,
        0x5C007B8A, 0x58C1663D, 0x558240E4, 0x51435D53,
        0x251D3B9E, 0x21DC2629, 0x2C9F00F0, 0x285E1D47,
        0x36194D42, 0x32D850F5, 0x3F9B762C, 0x3B5A6B9B,
        0x0315D626, 0x07D4CB91, 0x0A97ED48, 0x0E56F0FF,
        0x1011A0FA, 0x14D0BD4D, 0x19939B94, 0x1D528623,
        0xF12F560E, 0xF5EE4BB9, 0xF8AD6D60, 0xFC6C70D7,
        0xE22B20D2, 0xE6EA3D65, 0xEBA91BBC, 0xEF68060B,
        0xD727BBB6, 0xD3E6A601, 0xDEA580D8, 0xDA649D6F,
        0xC423CD6A, 0xC0E2D0DD, 0xCDA1F604, 0xC960EBB3,
        0xBD3E8D7E, 0xB9FF90C9, 0xB4BCB610, 0xB07DABA7,
        0xAE3AFBA2, 0xAAFBE615, 0xA7B8C0CC, 0xA379DD7B,
        0x9B3660C6, 0x9FF77D71, 0x92B45BA8, 0x9675461F,
        0x8832161A, 0x8CF30BAD, 0x81B02D74, 0x857130C3,
        0x5D8A9099, 0x594B8D2E, 0x5408ABF7, 0x50C9B640,
        0x4E8EE645, 0x4A4FFBF2, 0x470CDD2B, 0x43CDC09C,
        0x7B827D21, 0x7F436096, 0x7200464F, 0x76C15BF8,
        0x68860BFD, 0x6C47164A, 0x61043093, 0x65C52D24,
        0x119B4BE9, 0x155A565E, 0x18197087, 0x1CD86D30,
        0x029F3D35, 0x065E2082, 0x0B1D065B, 0x0FDC1BEC,
        0x3793A651, 0x3352BBE6, 0x3E119D3F, 0x3AD08088,
        0x2497D08D, 0x2056CD3A, 0x2D15EBE3, 0x29D4F654,
        0xC5A92679, 0xC1683BCE, 0xCC2B1D17, 0xC8EA00A0,
        0xD6AD50A5, 0xD26C4D12, 0xDF2F6BCB, 0xDBEE767C,
        0xE3A1CBC1, 0xE760D676, 0xEA23F0AF, 0xEEE2ED18,
        0xF0A5BD1D, 0xF464A0AA, 0xF9278673, 0xFDE69BC4,
        0x89B8FD09, 0x8D79E0BE, 0x803AC667, 0x84FBDBD0,
        0x9ABC8BD5, 0x9E7D9662, 0x933EB0BB, 0x97FFAD0C,
        0xAFB010B1, 0xAB710D06, 0xA6322BDF, 0xA2F33668,
        0xBCB4666D, 0xB8757BDA, 0xB5365D03, 0xB1F740B4}

    crc := uint32(0xffffffff)

    // different result
    for _, v := range message {
        crc = tbl[v^(byte(crc>>24)&0xff)] ^ (crc << 8)
    }

    crc = ^crc
    fmt.Printf("%10d == 0x%x\n", crc, crc) //  422667581 == 0x1931653d

    // same as http://zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html
    chk := crc32.ChecksumIEEE(message)
    fmt.Printf("%10d == 0x%x\n", chk, chk) //  907060870 == 0x3610a686
}
```

Edit (from a comment below): I understand that the source code of Go's crc32 and mine are different. But why is my implementation giving a different result? The table I am using has the same starting polynome (from [the wiki page for CRC-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)) as Go's implementation  (0x04C11DB7), except that Go uses the reversed polynome and therfore a different algorithm is not surprising. "My" algorithm comes from various different C/C++ sources, such as [the one linked in the source](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/repository/revisions/1cb52da49230c64c3719b4ab944ba1cf5a9abb92/entry/gr-digital/lib/digital_crc32.cc).

Comment: Except for two small problems, my code gives the same result as the `cksum` utility from unix. So it's not too far off.

Comment: My current finding: I see that there are many different standards of CRC-32s available. This page is linked from the wikipedia entry:  http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat-bits.32 - My first implementation is similar (modulo two errors) to the posix variant, the Go stdlib seems to implement the "plain crc-32".

Comment: @acw Same result, no change in calculation here.

Comment: agree, sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

First, it seem that you are not using the right table (or at least the same than the golang standard library): you can check it simply by comparing your table to the one available in the crc32 package. [Here is a playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/oUYM-6HYKL).

Then, you algorithm is also wrong. To be honest, I didn't even tried to check whether you put the right values at the right places, but simply dug out the code used by `crc32.Checksum`. Here is a fixed version of your algorithm:

`crc := uint32(0xffffffff)
for _, v := range message {
    crc = tbl[byte(crc)^v] ^ (crc >> 8)
}
return ^crc`

As you see, the in-loop calculation is a bit different. you can see it in action with the `crc32.IEEE` polynominal table [here](http://play.golang.org/p/eO_X_kRnwR).

Comment: I understand that the source code of Go's crc32 and mine are different. But why is my implementation giving a different result? The table I am using has the starting polynome from the wiki page for CRC-32 (0x04C11DB7), Go's implementation uses the reversed polynome.

Comment: From the wikipedia [mathematics of CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks#Reversed_representations_and_reciprocal_polynomials) :

*But the reciprocal polynomial is not the same as the original polynomial, and the CRCs generated using it are not the same (even modulo bit reversal) as those generated by the original polynomial.*

So yes, your result isn't the same as golang's one. Feel weird, but seem expected.

Comment: Is Go using reciprocal polynomials?

Comment: Hum… wrong quote. Non, Go isn't using reciprocal polynominals. But the reversed and normal versions doesn't give the same hexadecimal representation, so if you don't take it into account you won't get the same result.